# C# Add the message added to the list to the treeView when the button is pressed

Tags: c#, list, treeview

In the c# form application I developed, I would like to add the messages I added to the list to the treeview at the same time. I could do this in the messages that I added earlier to the .XML file, but I could not do it on the list.

```
public void buttonAddNewMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        addMessageList.Add(new AddedMessageList // ↓
                            { messageName = textMessageName.Text, // ↓
                                messageDirection = textMessageDirection.Text, // ↓
                                messageFrequency = textMessageFrequency.Text }); // → Listeye Mesaj Ekleme
    }
```

[image]

I share the picture of the application I developed for messages that I previously saved in the .xml file.
Now, I want to add the messages in the list to the treeView. The TreeView will only show the messageName.

```
public void PopulateTreeView(string name, TreeNode parentNode)
    {

        var filteredItems = addMessageList.Where(item => item.messageName == name);
        TreeNode childNode;

        foreach (var i in filteredItems.ToList())
        {

            if (parentNode == null)
            {

                childNode = messagesEditorObject.treeViewMessageList.Nodes.Add(i.messageName);
            }

            else
            {

                childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(i.messageName);
            }

            PopulateTreeView(i.messageName, childNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post the code which inserts the items into the tree view

Comment: what should be the expected result? do you want that `messageDirection` and `messageFrequency` are childnodes of the `messageName` ?

Comment: I want the messages I added to the list to be shown in the treeView as shown in the picture.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. You have an object `AddedMessageList` which consists of 3 variables `messageName`, `messageDirection` and  `messageFrequency`. What exactly does it mean: "I want the messages ...to be shown in the treeView". What format does a message have? "as shown in the picture." in the picture I see only a form with 3 Textboxes. Do you want to have 3 Textboxes in your treeview?

Comment: Every messages that are I added in the list<T> have a message name, message direction, and message frequence.
We should see just message names in the treeviews, not their direction and frequence. In the picture that I shared is just an example, now do not care about picture. 

Thing that I want to do does not have relation with xml. I want to do; when i press button, messages will add list<T> and also add treeview at the same time. how can I do that?

Comment: I posted an example how you could accomplish the adding into list and treeview at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It will be help your issue.

```
TreeNode nodeDirection = new TreeNode(textMessageDirection.Text);
TreeNode nodeFrequency = new TreeNode(textMessageFrequency.Text);
TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[] { nodeDirection , nodeFrequency };
treeNode = new TreeNode(textMessageName.Text, array);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```